# Vertical scrolling UIScrollview with Imageview and textview

Tags: uiscrollview, uiimageview, storyboard, autolayout, uitextview

I spent last 2 days trying to figure out UIScrollview using storyboard. Whenever I think I got it, a new problem appears and now it seams unsolvable.
Here is what I'm trying to do (it's really simple):

I have an Imageview 400x185 taking the whole width of the scrollview (edge to edge). That means that the scrollview has the width of the imageview.
Below is a textview that has <= width of the imageview.

I used many methods described on stackoverflow: 
- using a view on the scrollview and setting the width same as the parent of the scrollview.
- using just the scrollview without a view

All of them produced errors in the frame size of the image, size of the subview of scrollview, constrains, textview doesn't show up or the picture is too large even though I set the constrains edge to edge.

Can someone make a sample project with the UI described above? It would take 5 minutes for someone who knows how to deal with it.

Comment: what is the size of the `UIViewController`'s `UIView`? In other words, does the `UIScrollView` expand the whole screen?

Comment: @aytunch the size of the UIView is 400x600. The UIScrollView is put on the UIView and it takes the whole size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did this.  I know it works. Here is what I would suggest:

1. Make sure your 400x600 view is constrained to width 400 and height 600.
2. Add a scroll view to this view.  Have it take up the full view and then pin top, bottom, left, and right.
3. Add a UIView to the scroll view.  Have it take up the full view and then pin top, bottom, left, and right.  This is your content view.  I renamed my in the document outline to "ContentView".  At this point, you will have a warning about ambiguous content size, because until you add more constraints, the content view can grow to any size.
4. The size of the content view will be determined by the contents, so they need to be fully constrained.  Add the imageView to the content view.  Constrain its width to 400, constrain its height to 185.  Pin it to the left, top, and right of the contentView.  At this point, the contentView will know it is 400 wide, but it still doesn't know how tall it is.
5. Add the textView to the contentView.  Pin it a constant distance from the imageView. Constrain it to be centered in its contentView.  Pin it a constant distance from the bottom of the contentView.  Constrain its width to something less than 400 and its height to something big like 600.
6. At this point, the size of your contentView should be fully constrained.  It gets it width from the width of the imageView which is 400 wide and pinned to both sides of the contentView.  It gets its height from the constant distance of the imageView from the top + the height of the imageView + the constant distance between the imageView and the textView + the height of the textView + the constant distance from the textView to the bottom of the contentView.

---

If you want your scrollView to only scroll vertically, then constrain the contentView width to the scrollView width. This is easily done in the Document Outline view by control dragging from the contentView to the scrollView and then selecting *Equal Widths* from the pop up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The only thing that bothers me is that when I make the width of the imageview fixed like 400, on iphone5 simulator there is a horizontal scrolling bar too. I want that the content scales to the size of the iphone screen so only vertical scrolling bar appears. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Constrain the width of the contentView to the width of the top level view in the viewController which does match the width of the phone.  The easiest way to do this is to use the Document Outline view, control drag from the contentView to the top View and then select `Equal Widths` from the pop up.  Make sure you remove the imageView constraints or you'll end up with conflicting constraints.

Comment: Then you might want to remove the width and height constraints of the imageView, constrain its top, left, and right edges to the containerView, and then use an AspectRatio constraint to constrain the image width to the height to a 400:185 ratio.

Comment: I loaded the image in the imageview from the xcassets folder. I defined one universal image for all devices. When I launch the simulator the image appears huge and the horizontal scrolling bar appears because of it. The image still doesn't scale to the phone size. Does this have something to do with the image for universal devices? Do I have to define image width for every device and if so what would that width be? ps. This image is 640x280 pixels.

Comment: Did you constrain the content view width to the width of the top level view? That should keep the horizontal scrolling bars from appearing.  Then the image should be constrained on the leading and trailing edges with the content view.

Comment: I just did one from scratch with a big image, and it works fine.  Start with a fresh project.  Add scroll view, constrain all 4 edges.  Add a content view, constrain all 4 edges. Constrain content view "equal widths" with view controllers first view. Add image view, pin to top, left and right of content view.  Constrain aspect ratio.  Add text view, constrain it 20 points from bottom of content view, 20 points from both sizes of content view, and 20 points from image.  Constrain textView height to big value.  It will work on all devices, all orientations.

Comment: I did exactly that and it still doesn't follow the logic. Can you take a look at the project and see what did I do wrong? https://www.dropbox.com/s/j6zq75t4j7dvlbz/Vident.zip?dl=0

Comment: I just figured out something odd. The initial simulation shows the image like it is in landscape mode but when I rotate it to landscape and then return it back to portrait mode the image gets the correct size. Bug?

Comment: For some reason, your view doesn't auto layout until you rotate the device. Then if works fine after that.

Comment: It's certainly a bug.  I disconnected everything but your about us view controller, and it still happens.  It's not happening with mine.  Still looking for a cause.

Comment: So far, the only different thing I see is that you used wC hAny for your constraints.  I used wAny hAny.  You might want to consider doing wAny hAny as well since wC hAny doesn't cover iPhone 6 Plus.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help. Tomorrow I will start the project from scratch with the same setup. I will go ahead and accept your answer. If you figure out what the problem is I would appreciate it if you leave the solution in the comment.

Comment: I just recreated my project using wC hAny and it exhibits the same bug.  I think you'll be fine when you use wAny hAny.

Comment: I found a fix.  If you constrain the contentView to the scrollView (instead of the initial view) with equal widths it works.